# Disabling Gradle's “Using classes instead of jar for compilation”?

Tags: gradle

["Using classes instead of jar for compilation"](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_classes_usage) is causing me problems.  I am moving from the `java` plugin to the `java-library` one, which seems to be the cause.  Specifically referring to classes instead of jars for project dependencies when those projects define automatic Java 9 module names.  A module that defines an explicit module-info.java and tries to `require` the module with an automatic name will fail because the automatic name is only known through the module's jar file manifest.

I can verify that setting `org.gradle.java.compile-classpath-packaging` does resolve the issue, but I'd really prefer a way to disable that for the specific "importing" module.  Is that possible?

FWIW, attempting to set `org.gradle.java.compile-classpath-packaging` in the project's gradle.properties file does *not* work.

Cross-posted as https://discuss.gradle.org/t/disable-using-classes-instead-of-jar-for-compilation/39835

Thanks!